# Programmatically check if user's OneDrive is provisioned via Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

My unattended DotNet Core app uses Graph SDK to check files in particular OneDrive folders for every user in an Azure AD group. For some users then it catches exceptions "User's mysite not found" & "Unable to retrieve user's mysite URL" when getting the drive list. These exceptions are typically due to the OneDrive account not being provisioned

Is there a way to programmatically detect if the OneDrive account has not been provisioned?
Does anyone know why there are 2 slightly different errors?

Ideally I want to ignore these users but still report these errors for other users where OneDrive has been provisioned. I assume that these errors can happen for other reasons.